# TFS/VSTS/Azure Devops - Cannot run tests from test plan using associated automation

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, vstest

After setting up the release definition with tasks exactly like those in this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops

I am continuing to get the error:

`Selected environment does not have the right version or settings of the Visual Studio Test task to run tests.`

My current configuration can be seen below.

Link to screenshot of VsTest task.

[image: Link to screenshot of VsTest task.]

Has anyone experienced this problem before? If so, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed Visual Studio on the agent computer, otherwise you must add the [Visual Studio Test Platform Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment?view=azure-devops) to the pipeline definition.